# MYSQL - edit JSON object that is in array of json object

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, json, sql-update

**Table name**

`guilds`

**Data**

```
members = {
    'look': [{
        id: '123',
        bot: false,
        username: 'Joe',
    }, {
        id: '456',
        bot: false,
        username: 'Jeff',
    }]
};
```

'look' contains a bunch of json objects.
'members' is name of a row in table 'guilds'.
My goal is to edit the name of user with id '123' to Janett.

Using MYSQL 8.0 with JavaScript. (using module mysql, Node.js).

**I tried**

I tried to get the members row then parse the result and assign new value to the corresponding field. Turns out that mysql does not have any function to update it from there as mongoose does.

```
connection.query(`SELECT members FROM guilds WHERE id='${_guild_id}'`, (err, result) => {
   let parse = JSON.parse(result[0].members);
   parse.look.forEach(element => {
      if (element.id === '123') {
        element.username = "some name"
      }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to entirely unnest the array into columns and rows with `json_table`, then rebuild the object (this requires that you know the comple structure of the object beforehand).

As a starter, consider the following `select` query, that parses, modifies and rebuilds the object:

```
select json_object(
    'look', 
    json_arrayagg(
        json_object(
            'id', j.id, 
            'bot', j.bot, 
            'username', case when j.id = 123 then 'Janett' else j.username end
        )
    )
) v
from guilds g
cross join json_table(
    g.members ->> '$.look',
    '$[*]'
    columns (
        id int path '$.id',
        bot boolean path '$.bot',
        username varchar(100) path '$.username'
    )
) j
where id = 1
```

You can then turn this to an `update` query, if that's what you want:

```
update guilds g
inner join (
    select g.id, json_object(
        'look', 
        json_arrayagg(
            json_object(
                'id', j.id, 
                'bot', j.bot, 
                'username', case when j.id = 123 then 'Janett' else j.username end
            )
        )
    ) new_members
    from guilds g
    cross join json_table(
        g.members ->> '$.look',
        '$[*]'
        columns (
            id int path '$.id',
            bot boolean path '$.bot',
            username varchar(100) path '$.username'
        )
    ) j
    where g.id = 1
    group by g.id
) x
on g.id = x.id
set g.members = x.new_members
```